# matrix multiplication convergence problem

Tags: linear-algebra, convergence-divergence

Suppose A is a square matrix.

Does $A^n$(matrix multiplication) converge when n is an infinite big number？

Is it always true or under certain circumstances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of the matrix $A$ is $J$, then you have $A=PJP^{-1}$ and this yields $A^n=PJ^nP^{-1}$. So we only have to ask when powers of the Jordan blocks of the given matrix converge. The structure of powers of Jordan blocks is [relatively simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Powers).

It is relatively easy to see that the power $A^n$ converges to zero matrix if $|\lambda|<1$ for all eigenvalues of $A$. (See e.g. the result at the end of [this text](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/m640_03c/lectures/chapter8.pdf).)

If the only eigenvalue with absolute value 1 is 1 and the corresponding Jordan blocks have size 1, then it converges. If there is a Jordan block corresponding to 1 of size at least 2, then the power does not converge. (This was pointed out by Ted in the comments, thanks for the correction.)

If there are complex eigenvalues different from 1 with $|\lambda|=1$ then the power does not converge.

If it has an eigenvalue with $|\lambda|>1$, it does not converge.

Comment: In which case they converge to the zero matrix

Comment: @jspecter Thanks for your commment, I've added it to the answer.

Comment: If there is an eigenvalue 1 in a Jordan block $J$ of size > 1, then the powers of the Jordan block won't converge: $J=I+N$ where $N$ is a nonzero nilpotent matrix with entries in $\{0,1\}$, so $(I+N)^k$ equals $I + kN + C(k,2)N^2 + \ldots + N^k$.  The off-diagonal entries go to $\infty$ as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: @Ted I have overlooked this possibility, thanks for noticing and notifying me. I've corrected this part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The convergence properties of $A^n$ are fully understood by studying the eigenspectrum of $A$. The work http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0671.pdf by H.H. Bauschke thoroughly covers the subject, and beyond.

For example, a sufficient condition for convergence is that the spectral radius of $A$ be strictly less than $1$. In fact, in this case, $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim}A^n = 0$.