# Convergence of $A^n v$ for a matrix $A$ and a vector $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67375/matrix-multiplication-convergence-problem) question, Martin Sleziak shows that for a complex square matrix $A$, we have $$\lim A^n = 0 $$ if and only if the spectral radius of $A$ is less than $1$. I was wondering what happens if we are interested only in the convergence with respect to a given vector.

To be more specific, suppose now that all eigenvalues of $A$ have modulus $\ge 1$ and let v be some given vector such that $$\lim A^n v = 0. $$ Does it imply that $ v = 0 $?

I suspect the answer is yes, but I don't know how to deal with the case where two distinct eigenvalues of $A$ have the same modulus.

**Edit:** The comments encouraged me to add more details. Let $J$ be the Jordan form of $A$ and $P$ such that $A=PJP^{-1}$. Then
$$A^n =
P\begin{pmatrix}
J_1^n & \;     & \; \\
\;  & \ddots & \; \\ 
\;  & \;     & J_m^n
\end{pmatrix}P^{-1} $$
where $J_i$ is a Jordan block of size $k_i\times k_i$, so that

$$ J_i^n = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_i^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda_i^{n-1} & \binom{n}{2}\lambda_i^{n-2} & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k_i-1}\lambda_i^{n-k_i+1} \\
 & \lambda_i^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda_i^{n-1} & \cdots & \cdots & \binom{n}{k_i-2}\lambda_i^{n-k_i+2} \\
 &  & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 &  & & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
 &  & &  & \lambda_i^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda_i^{n-1}\\
 &  &  &  &  & \lambda_i^n
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Thus every entry of $A^n v$ has the form
$$\tag{1}\label{sum}\sum_{i=1}^m p_i(n)\lambda_i^n$$
where $p_i$ is a complex polynomial such that $\deg p_i< k_i$ for $i=1,\dots,m$.

So essentially what I'm asking is this:

Suppose $|\lambda_i|\ge1$ for $i=1,\dots,m$ and that \eqref{sum} converges to $0$ (when $n\to\infty$). Does it imply that the sequence \eqref{sum} is identically zero?

Comment: Why do you find this specific case to be problematic?

Comment: Look at the norm of A, use the leading eigenvalue of A to bound that born, and see that the norm grows without bound. Therefore x if the limit exists, it must be zero.

Comment: @Ben Grossman If $v$ is the sum of some generalized eigenvectors that correspond to eigenvalues of the same modulus, $A^n v$ can still be arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: @Leo I'm not sure how to do it when there does not exist a unique dominant eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Schur triangulation, we may assume that $A$ is lower triangular. Hence all diagonal elements of $A$ (which are the eigenvalues of $A$) have moduli greater than $1$. Since $A$ is lower triangular, the first entry of $A^nv$ is $a_{11}^nv_1$. By assumption, $|a_{11}|\ge1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{11}^nv_1=0$. Hence $v_1$ is necessarily zero. But then the second entry of $A^nv$ is $a_{22}^nv_2$. Using a similar argument to the above, we can show that $v_2=0,v_3=0,\ldots$ and so on. Hence $v=0$.

Comment: I thought at first that the modulus of $u A^n v $ can be bounded from below if $v\neq 0$, but if for example $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal then this sequence is identically zero, so I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @MCL Good point. Please see my new edit.

Comment: I don't see why we can assume that $A$ is triangular. The form of the entries of  $A^n v$ after changing the basis is more complicated as it might involve multiple eigenvalues and need not be bounded below. For instance, for a matrix with the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ we might have an entry $(-1)^n + 1$. I have edited the question to include these details.

Comment: @MCL That $A$ is similar to a triangular matrix is guaranteed by Schur's theorem.

Comment: The thing that was bothering me was how to deduce the general case from the triangular matrix one, but I think I get it now: Suppose $A^n v \to 0$ and write $A = P^{-1}LP$ where $L$ is triangular. Then $\|L^n Pv\|= \| PA^n v\|\le \|P\|\|A^n v\|\to0$, hence $Pv=0$ and $v=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**: if $A$ has all eigenvalues of modulus at least one, and $\lim_{k\to\infty} A^kv = 0$, then $v=0$.

---

Let me first give a slick answer in the case that all eigenvalues of $A$ have modulus $r>1$. The spectral radius of $A^{-1}$ is $r^{-1} < 1$. For all $v$,
$$ |v| = |A^{-n} A^n v| \leq |A^{-n}| |A^n v|.$$
The spectral radius $\rho$ satisfies $\rho(B) = \lim_{k \to \infty} |B^k|^{1/k}$ for all matrix norms $|\cdot|$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}|A^{-n}|^{1/n} = r^{-1}$.
Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $|A^nv| \leq \epsilon$ and $|A^{-n}|^{1/n} < 1$ for $n \geq N$, hence $|v| \leq \epsilon$. This shows that $v = 0$.

---

The following works for general (upper-triangular) Jordan blocks of eigenvalue with modulus $\geq 1$. Let $J$ be a block of size $n$ with eigenvalue $\alpha$. We prove that if $\lim_{k\to\infty} J^k v =0$, then $v = 0$. The proof is by induction on $n$. For $n=0$, $v=0$ and we're done. In general, the $n$th entry of $J^k v$ is $\alpha^k v_n$, which tends to zero if and only if $v_n = 0$. Hence $v$ is in the domain of $J$ restricted to the upper $(n-1)\times(n-1)$-block, which is a Jordan block of size one smaller. Now induct to finish the proof.

Essentially, the polynomials $p_i$ you reference are not so complicated since one is always constant.

Comment: I understand the first part of your answer, thanks. But in the general case, I still don't see how to apply your answer to a matrix with multiple Jordan blocks and which is not necessarily in Jordan form. Take for example the linear transformation $A$ defined by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \lambda_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \lambda_2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ for some $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ of modulus $1$.

Comment: Then $A^n \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1^n+\lambda_2^n \\ \lambda_1^n-\lambda_2^n \end{pmatrix}$, and in this case the last entry is more complicated than $\alpha^k v_n$, even though both polynomials that correspond to this entry are constant $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: The question does not depend on the choice of coordinates. Just change basis to Jordan form first.